# Finding shortest routes between multiple origins and destinations?

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, routing

For example, I have 100 origin points and 100 destination points. All points are connected to each other. I want to know the route between each origin and each destination. How do I do it all at once?

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved with the OD Cost Matrix.
The thing is you get the length of the route in the table, but the route will shown as a straight line between origin and destination.